# Sending email with multiple checkboxes using php

Tags: php, mysql

In this code i can't able to print the echo statement how can i able to know whether this code is sending mail or not. I'm a web designer not developer. if the echo statement is working means i can undestand that the code is working properly.

```
        if(isset($_REQUEST['email']))
        {
        echo "dfsdkf";

            // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
            $email_to = "info@ltnts.com";
            $email_subject = "Enquiry Details From ltnt.in";


        $customer_name=$_REQUEST['fullname'];
        $organisation=$_REQUEST['cmp_name'];
        $phone_num=$_REQUEST['contact'];
        $email=$_REQUEST['logo_emailid'];
        $country=$_REQUEST['country'];
        $state=$_REQUEST['state'];
        $city=$_REQUEST['logo_city'];
        $zipcode=$_REQUEST['logo_zipcode'];
        $project_type=$_REQUEST['market_type'];
        $website_url=$_REQUEST['logo_name'];
        $website_purpose=$_REQUEST['business_desc'];
        $website_keyword=$_REQUEST['web_keyword'];
        $Competitors=$_REQUEST['targent_aud'];
        $sample_websites=$_REQUEST['targent_aud1'];
        $no_of_updation=$_REQUEST['updation'];
        $required_pages=$_REQUEST['checkbox'];
        $additional_page=$_REQUEST['addition_page'];
        $other_details=$_REQUEST['other_d'];



            function clean_string($string) {
              $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
              return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
            }

            $email_message .= "Customer Name: ".clean_string($customer_name)."\n";
            $email_message .= "organisation: ".clean_string($organisation)."\n";
            $email_message .= "phone_num: ".clean_string($phone_num)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Email ID: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Country: ".clean_string($country)."\n";
            $email_message .= "state: ".clean_string($state)."\n";
            $email_message .= "city: ".clean_string($city)."\n";
            $email_message .= "zipcode: ".clean_string($zipcode)."\n";
            $email_message .= "project_type: ".clean_string($project_type)."\n";
            $email_message .= "website_url: ".clean_string($website_url)."\n";
            $email_message .= "website_purpose: ".clean_string($website_purpose)."\n";
            $email_message .= "website_keyword ID: ".clean_string($website_keyword)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Competitors: ".clean_string($Competitors)."\n";
            $email_message .= "sample_websites: ".clean_string($sample_websites)."\n";
            $email_message .= "no_of_updation: ".clean_string($no_of_updation)."\n";
            //$email_message .= "required_pages: ".clean_string($required_pages)."\n";
            $email_message .= "additional_page: ".clean_string($additional_page)."\n";
            $email_message .= "other_details: ".clean_string($other_details)."\n";

            $newsletter = $_POST['checkbox'];

           if ($newsletter != 'Yes') 
           {
            $newsletter = 'No';
           }
        $email_message .="Selected:".clean_string($newsletter)."\n";

            // create email headers
        $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
        'Reply-To: '.$email_to."\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
        }
        else
        {
        echo "dfjdhfjshfjz";
        }

        ?>
    <input name="checkbox[] "type="checkbox" name="page_Home" value="Home" id="pageHome" onChange="toggleVisibility('home');" /><label for="pageHome"> Home</label><img id="home" src="images/icon-tick.png"  style="visibility:hidden"/><br/>

    <input name="checkbox[]" value="About_us" id="page_Aboutus" type="checkbox" onChange="toggleVisibility('aboutus');"><label for="page_Aboutus"> About Us</label><img id="aboutus" src="images/icon-tick.png"  style="visibility:hidden" /><br/>

    <input name="checkbox[]" value="Services" id="pageServices" type="checkbox" onChange="toggleVisibility('services');"><label for="pageServices"> Services</label><img id="services" src="images/icon-tick.png"  style="visibility:hidden" /><br/>

    <input name="checkbox[]" value="Products" id="pageProducts" type="checkbox" onChange="toggleVisibility('products');"><label for="pageProducts"> Products</label><img id="products" src="images/icon-tick.png"  style="visibility:hidden"/><br/>

    <input name="checkbox[]" value="Enquiry" id="pageEnquiry" type="checkbox" onChange="toggleVisibility('enquiry');"><label for="pageEnquiry"> Enquiry</label><img id="enquiry" src="images/icon-tick.png"  style="visibility:hidden"/><br/>

    <input name="checkbox[]" value="Contact_us" id="pageContact" type="checkbox" onChange="toggleVisibility('Contact');"><label for="pageContact">Contact Us</label><img id="Contact" src="images/icon-tick.png"  style="visibility:hidden" /><br/>
```

Comment: if you can't see the first `echo` after `if(isset($_REQUEST['email']))` the the problem is that in your request (`$_GET` or `$_POST`) you don't have the parameter `email`

Comment: i have checked with Both $_GET and $_POST but i didnt get solution bro:-)

Comment: And remove `@` in development, could be useful in production to silence errors (i don't like too much because i don't have control on this) but not in development.

Comment: And you have the parameter in `$_REQUEST`? Post your `$_REQUEST` (`print_r($_REQUEST)`)

Comment: no i have not called anywhere like $_REQUEST? or $_REQUEST (print_r($_REQUEST))

Comment: No, write `print_r($_REQUEST)` before the first `if` and see if *email* is set or not

Comment: its printing the values whatever i'm inserting into the textfields. how can i know that its sent or not. suggest me..

Answer (score 0):

First check if `$_REQUEST['email']` is set and in order to know if code is sending mail or not

You can use `error_get_last()`, when `mail()` returns false.

With print_r(error_get_last()) you get proper error

mail() returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.

It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does   not mean the mail will reach the destination.

use @mail to suppress warnings

Use

```
if( @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers) ) {
  echo 'mail send';

} else {
 print_r(error_get_last());
}
```

Comment: i have used this code its not printing anything. blank page is displaying

Comment: please can u able to send the code for that.. i'm not good programmer.

Comment: omg.. i didn't get any proper solution.. whatever u people are telling i'm trying but its simply displaying blank page